# What describes the value of RecommendedItem for a Boolean-Recommender

Tags: mahout

If one calculates the recommendations for a boolean DataModel, the RecommendedItems have some numbers in their value field. 
What does it represent? (Understandably, it can't be the calculated preference).

The class  GenericRecommendedItem-API only says: "A value expressing the strength of the preference for the recommended item. The range of the values depends on the implementation. Implementations must use larger values to express stronger preference."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intentionally opaque so you don't rely on any particular value. It happens to be a sum of similarities if I recall correctly -- all similarities between the user's items and that item.